# UICollectionView dynamic header size calculation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know there are already a lot of posts around this topic, but they somehow didn't lead me to a solution and at this point, after trying for days I don't know what to do.

So I have a `UICollectionView` where I have a header. For the header I created my own `UICollectionReusableView`. It contains a StackView with two labels in it. Both of them have dynamic sizes (Lines = 0). These are the the constraints for the StackView (I also tried setting the bottom constraint to = 0):

**StackView constraints**

[image: screen shot]

I calculate the header size like this...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let item = displayItems.object(at: UInt(section)) as! MySectionDisplayItem

    let reusableView: MyReusableView = UIView.fromNib()
    reusableView.setTitle(text: item.getTitle())
        .setSubtitle(subtitle: item.getSubtitle())

    return reusableView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
}
```

...and return the view to be displayed like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let item = displayItems.object(at: UInt(indexPath.section)) as! MySectionDisplayItem

    let reusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "myReusableView", for: indexPath) as! MyReusableView

    reusableView.setTitle(text: item.getTitle())
        .setSubtitle(subtitle: item.getSubtitle())

    return reusableView
}
```

In my `UICollectionReusableView` and `UICollectionView` Auto Layout is enabled.

Some things I tried:

- set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to different positive values on my labels
- embed the labels in separate views
- work with constraints instead of using a StackView

I hope I didn't mix up some of the solutions I found, but anyways I don't think such a "simple" thing can be that hard to realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by constraining the width:

```
reusableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
reusableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
```

Might be that you also have to play around with content compression resistances.